# how to insert json into a json array in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've been trying to append a JSON object to an already-populated array in a JSON column. I tried to use the `JSON_ARRAY_INSERT()` function but it didn't work as expected.

I have the following table:

| id (`BIGINT`) | json_data (`JSON`) |
| --- | --- |
| `3` | `[{"a":"0","b":"1"}]` |

And I want to append another object `{"c":"2","d":"3"}` to the existing array. Here is what I tried:

```php
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exampledb", "root", "");
$query="UPDATE example SET json_data = JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(json_data, '$[1]', :new_json_data) WHERE id = 3";
$result = $conn->prepare($query);
$result->execute([
    "new_json_data" => json_encode(["c" => "2", "d" => "3"])
]);
```

I want the `json_data` column value to be

```json
[{"a":"0","b":"1"},{"c":"2","d":"3"}]
```

But the result is

```json
[{"a":"0","b":"1"}, "{\"c\":\"2\",\"d\":\"3\"}"]
```

Comment: By default, PHP uses PDO::PARAM_STR for variables to bind, so that could be the answer. Make sure your query is working as expected when you execute it right on MySQL to exclude that query is not working after that try removing json_encode which return string as result.

Comment: I've attempted to make your code and question more readable. Using consistent indentation and whitespace in your code is common courtesy for other users here, and will also help you when you're writing and debugging your own code. I removed a leading backslashed quote from your JSON output which looked like a mistake; it was not matched up with any other backslashed quote mark.

Comment: Also as a side note, `JSON_ARRAY_INSERT()` puts the inserted object at a specific place in the array. If you just want it at the very end, you are probably looking for `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(json_data, '$', CAST(:new_json_data AS JSON))`

Comment: Ok, fixed that. Using preformatted code blocks will make things easier for you in the future.

Comment: i see thanks for the side note and for the editting too , its my first time asking a question so my editting sucks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$query="update example set json_data=JSON_ARRAY_INSERT(json_data,'$[1]',
    CAST(:new_json_data AS JSON)) where id=3";
```

This will force the string input to be converted to a JSON document before appending it to the array.

Comment: that gave me the same result

Comment: well guess what , that works , i had two identical blocs of code and i was only edditing the one that i wasnt executing thank you very much for the answer Bill